# What are Edge Webview2 specified JS APIs?

Tags: javascript, c#, webview, webview2

Is there a way to find Edge Webview2 specified JS APIs, that are not a part of standard Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

WebView2 has two sets of JavaScript APIs that are described in the reference docs:

- [`CoreWebView2.WebMessageReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2?view=webview2-1.0.1020.30#add_webmessagereceived) and [`CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2?view=webview2-1.0.1020.30#postwebmessageasjson) describe the JavaScript APIs to post and receive messages to and from the CoreWebView2:

  - `chrome.webview.postMessage` function
  - `chrome.webview.addEventListener('message', ...)` event.
- [`CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2?view=webview2-1.0.1020.30#addhostobjecttoscript) describes the various JavaScript proxy objects for interacting with host objects added via that method:

  - `chrome.webview.hostObjects`